# Какая форма прошедшего времени у слова «приемлет»?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, глаголы, времена

> Он не приемлет *что-либо*.

А есть ли форма прошедшего времени у «приемлет»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПРИЯ́ТЬ, прош. прия́л, -ла, -ло; сов., перех. (несов. принимать). Устар. Взять, получить, принять. Или, свой подвиг свершив, я стою, как поденщик ненужный, Плату приявший свою, чуждый работе другой? Пушкин, Труд. (Малый академический словарь, МАС), см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C).

Как видно, у данного глагола инфинитив — **приять**, форма же прошедшего времени — **приял** (см. [здесь](https://www.translate.ru/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82)). В "Нацкорпусе" есть множество соответствующих примеров из литературы (см. [здесь](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BB)), приведу несколько.

*Я **приял** российский либерализм в его идеологической сущности, без какого-либо партийного догматизма. [А. И. Деникин. Путь русского офицера (1944-1947)]*

*Гуляй себе по Дону и заживляй раны, которые **приял** за отечество, а когда назад будешь через Тулу ехать, ― остановись и спосылай за нами: мы к той поре, Бог даст, что-нибудь придумаем. [Н. С. Лесков. Левша (1881)]*

*Он жил среди красот и аки Ахиллес На ратном поле вдруг он мужество изнес: Впервый **приял** он гром, и гром ему послушен, Впервые встретил смерть ― и встретил равнодушен! [В. В. Огарков. Григорий Потемкин. Его жизнь и общественная деятельность (1892)]*

*Многие потерпели в правде, многие **прияли** венец мученический, Никита Романыч! [Толстой А. К., Князь Серебряный, 1862]*

*— Померла, сударь, **прияла** успокоение, — отвечал священник. — Сном праведника почила, на редкость у младенцев такая тихая кончина. [Писемский А. Ф., Боярщина, 1846]*